# SoundPool call to play results only in error log

Tags: android, soundpool

I'm encountering an issue when I moved my SoundPool instance to a separate thread and class.

No sound plays, though all the streams and status flags are successful.

I'm getting the following output in the error log:

```
D/chris﹕ before play
E/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ getOutput() IOProfile is null.
E/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ getOutput() IOProfile is null.
E/AudioPolicyManagerBase﹕ getOutput() IOProfile is null.
D/libc﹕ pt_debug : pthread_create->start_routine=0x402c8509, tls=0x55c6ff00, arg=0x512c4370
D/libc﹕ pt_debug : __thread_entry->func=0x402c8509 , tls=0x55c6ff00, arg=0x512c4370
D/chris﹕ after play
```

Does anyone have any clue as to what these errors indicate?

```
public class SoundPoolFactory extends Thread {

    public SoundPool soundPool;
    public HashMap<String, AssetFileDescriptor> soundLoadList = new HashMap<String, AssetFileDescriptor>();

    public void run()
    {
        Looper.prepare();
        looper = Looper.myLooper();

        soundPool = new SoundPool(3, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
        soundPool.setOnLoadCompleteListener(new SoundPool.OnLoadCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
                soundLoaded.release();
            }
        });

        Iterator iterator = soundLoadList.entrySet().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext())
        {
            Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)iterator.next();
            loadSound((AssetFileDescriptor)entry.getValue(), (String)entry.getKey());
        }

        Looper.loop();
    }

    public void loadSound(AssetFileDescriptor assetFile, String soundIndex)
    {
        try {
            soundIndexes.put(soundIndex, soundPool.load(assetFile, 1));
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter( writer );
            e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
            printWriter.flush();

            Log.e("chris", writer.toString());
        }
    }

    public SoundPool getSoundPoolInstance()
    {
        try {
            Log.d("chris", "before play");
            soundPool.play(1, 1.0f, 1.0f,1,0,1.0f);
            Log.d("chris", "after play");
            return soundPool;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter( writer );
            e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
            printWriter.flush();

            Log.e("chris", writer.toString());
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Any luck with this problem?  I'm seeing the same errors in my log.

Comment: I honestly can't remember. I'm guessing I solved it though. Take a look here: https://github.com/chrissound/SoundPoolFacade